# I upgraded to macOS Sierra. Now my disk utility doesn't show what types of files are taking up space

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

I have a mid-2012 Macbook Pro (non-retina) running macOS Sierra and I recently upgraded the hard drive to a 240GB SSD and moved the 500GB HDD to the CD bay, and then more recently upgrading to MacOS Sierra. Now in disk utility it does not show what file types are taking up space like it used to in all the previous versions of OS X. Am I being stupid or is this a glitch?

Screenshots:

[image: Screencap 1]

[image: Screencap 2]

Comment: Try opening System Profiler to show the breakdown of what's on the disk. You can get there by clicking the apple logo in the status bar, clicking About Mac, and then clicking storage. This should give a real breakdown of what is on the disk.

Comment: @bret7600 This works... sort of. It says that I have 90GB of documents, which can't possibly be correct. It appears to be counting all my video footage as documents. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight can get stuck and show you wrong information, so right after an update, you might need to wait a day or so if you don't leave the computer running.

Open About This Mac from the Apple menu and then select Storage:

[image]

The gross storage should match Disk Utility which his out of the business of knowing what's in the drive - just that it's used. If you get a blank or wrong diagram - there's no progress bar letting you know background processes are recalculating, but eventually you should see a better image like below:

[image]

Note:

- the size of the free space is NOT TO SCALE.  I have 45% and 42% free space above but the "free space" white area is clearly not to scale.
- the "System" can include data from other users that you might expect to be calculated as photos or documents or videos. Even some of your iCloud data can get lumped into System.